# File type custom field to only allow images

Tags: custom-fields, custom

I have created a file type custom field and discovered that you can upload any type of file on the field so I want to restrict the custom field to only upload image files. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [validateForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_validateForm/) in an extension to restrict it.

You can also vote for this ticket: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2410

Comment: Although it didn't directly fix my problem but this helped me get the idea how to fix it.. thanks